# отваливается шаблоны после изменения html или css в gulp-file-include

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, frontend, npm

Всем привет, использую gulp в верстке и столкнулся с такой проблемой.Установил я пакет gulp-file-include, настроил таск в gulp.js
подключаю шаблон header на главную, запускаю gulp работает вроде все нормально, но как только делаю изменения в html или css то сразу отваливается подключения шаблона header и выводит просто строку @include('layouts/header.html').Компилирую заново и опять все нормально, такое ощущение что watch не находит эти изменения, в чем проблема я короче не знаю, скрины и код смотрите ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<body class="homepage">
  <!-- start header section -->
  @include('layouts/header.html')  вот собственно этот участок кода
  <!-- end header section -->
 
   <!-- дальше пошли блоки с контентом -->
</body>


const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");
const htmlmin = require("gulp-htmlmin");
const fileinclude = require("gulp-file-include");

gulp.task('server', function () {

    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "dist"
        }
    });

    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src("src/scss/**/*.+(scss|sass)")
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min', prefix: '' }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(cleanCSS({ compatibility: 'ie8' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch("src/scss/**/*.+(scss|sass|css)", gulp.parallel('styles'));
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', gulp.parallel('html'));
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src("src/*.html")
        .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/"));
}); 

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src("src/js/**/*.js")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/js"));
});

gulp.task('fileinclude', function(){
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.html'])
    .pipe(fileinclude({
        prefix: '@',
        basepath: '@file'
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());
})

gulp.task('fonts', function () {
    return gulp.src("src/fonts/**/*")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/fonts"));
});

gulp.task('icons', function () {
    return gulp.src("src/icons/**/*")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/icons"));
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src("src/img/**/*")
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/img"));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch', 'server', 'styles','scripts','fonts','fileinclude','html','icons','images'));
```

Comment: я в этом не разбираюсь, но явно же видно, что таск watch никак не вызывает таск fileinclude, а таск default - вызывает

Comment: gulp.watch(['src/*.html', 'index.html'], gulp.series(fileinclude, browserSyncReload));
надо сделать что-то типо такого? я недавно начал gulp учить есть моменты которые не могу понять

Comment: раньше писали так: `gulp.task('server', ['watch'], function () {`. как сейчас устроено - не знаю. в watch не хватает fileinclude